# Method name expected- using lambda expressions wrong?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am implementing a `Contains(T item)` method in a custom collection.
The following works(since it is basically a copy of Microsoft's implementation):

```
public class aCollection:IEnumerable<T>
{
T[] items;
public int Count{ get; private set;}
//...
public bool Contains(T item)
{
    EqualityComparer<T> defaultComparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        if (defaultComparer.Equals(items[i], item))
            return true;
    return false;
}
}
```

However, while coming to this solution I have tried another way around it, yet I fails to understand the exact reason why the build fails with `Method name expected` error:

```
public class aCollection:IEnumerable<T>
{
T[] items;
public int Count{ get; private set;}
//...
public bool Contains(T item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        if ((x => x == item)(items[i]))    //Method name expected
            return true;
    return false;
}
}
```

What am I misunderstanding here in the usage of lambdas? Is it a case where I can't use them for some reason or maybe I just wrote the expression wrong?

EDIT: What I expect the function to do is to check my collection to find out, if it contains the argument. The line in the for loop is supposed to compare the existing elements in the `T[] items` to the passed `T item` one by one, until a match is found and return `true`. Alternatively, if no match is found in the whole array, just return `false`.

Thanks in advance,

hlfrmn

Comment: I assume error is on `if ((x => x == item)(items[i]))` line, but I can't figure out what you actually wanted to do there... Some sentence about "I expected this to do ....." could help to clarify what exactly you did not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda expressions should be converted to a delegate to be used. The following code looks weird, but there will be no compilation error with lambda:

```
public bool Contains(T item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        if (((Func<T, bool>)((T x) => x == item))(items[i]))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

To avoid creating a new delegate at every iteration, it can be stored before the cycle:

```
public bool Contains(T item)
{
    Func<T, bool> comparer = (T x) => x == item;

    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        if (comparer(items[i]))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

But it still has an important problem: the operator `==` is not defined for generic types (like C++). I suggest using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to compare the values.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. While waiting for an answer I actually managed to get past the initial error, by using `Predicate<T> myPred = ((x) => x == item);`, which got me to the undefined `==` operator problem. The Func cast looks more funny that weird to me

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    if ((x => x == item)(items[i]))
        return true;
```

Simply using the `Any` LINQ method and pass the lambda expression like this:

```
if (items.Any(x => x == item))
    return true;
```

If for some reason need to use the lambda expression as a function (which seems to be what you are trying to do), then you can do it like this:

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>> lambda_expression = (x => x == item);

Func<T, bool> function = lambda_expression.Compile();

for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
    if (function(items[i]))
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the LINQ advice. I was not as much trying to solve the problem with a naked lambda exclusively, as trying to find out about an error I accidentally stumbled upon. Would there be any difference between  `Func<T,bool> f= Expression<Func<T,bool>>.Compile` and  ' ((Func<T, bool>)((T x) => x == item)) (arg)` usages?

Comment: No, it's the same. The second way does an implicit conversion from the lambda expression to a function

Comment: However, I am not sure if performance would be the same. You can test to verify.

Comment: I actually made a simple test, and the results seem to favor the "shorter" version, it being around 4000 times faster. The result seems kind of strange, so I wouldn't take my own word for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with your approach, change your code to

```
public bool Contains(T item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        if (items[i].Equals(item))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Here you are explicitly iterating over the collection, so no need to use lambda. When you write this
`if ((x => x == item)(items[i]))` - compiler does not understand what `x` is referring to!

If you want to use lambda, you can write in a more elegant way like

```
public bool Contains(T item)
{
    return items.Any(i => i.Equals(item));
}
```

Note: Use `EquityComparer` default, like the MSDN example, otherwise you'll miss any `EqualityComparer` that the type `T` might have implemented. Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx) for `EquityComparer.Default.

**Update**

If you see the *`CLR core libraries`*, this is how *`.Any()`* has been implemented

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (predicate(element)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, from the actual implementation, you can see it does exactly what you are trying to do. You can see other *`Linq Enumerable Extensions`* in this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) and explore the implementations of other standard Linq methods.

Comment: Thanks for the MSDN link, haven't seen it yet. As for the LINQ Any, I am not too familiar yet with how it's implemented, so I was more or less exploring the available methods and their implementations.

Comment: @hlfrmn I've updated the answer to include Any() method body from CLR. I hope the updated answer will help you understand it better.

Comment: Thank you for the update. While I do know the way it works now, I'm afraid I can't use it, since some elements in the array are beyond the Count index, so they are kept in memory, while technically being unreachable by methods due to Count checks. Any foreach() loop would iterate throughout the whole collection, also checking these "deleted" values. I am thinking of triggering a TrimCapacity() function after every remove-like operation, but still have yet to give life to the idea.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, a better solution is ***not*** to implement your own `Contains()` method at all.

Since your custom collection implements `IEnumerable<T>`, then it means that you get all the `IEnumerable<T>` LINQ extension methods for free, including [Enumerable.Contains<TSource> Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx). No need to roll out your own.